# Error: Key already exists

Tags: python, json, postgresql, facebook-graph-api, psycopg2

I'm using postgres (psycopg2) and python to get information from facebook page. I get a json object and iterate over any posts in order to create and concatenate the insert query string. Just with some users, I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  A duplicate key value violates the unique constraint "fb_post_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (id) = (xxx) already exists.
```

What should I do in order to commit the query? Could I delete, from the json object, duplicate key?

Comment: Post sample data.

Comment: from constraint name I believe you could use `ON CONFLICT DO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which means that your database is doing it's job properly. Your table is configured not to allow duplicates. There are two ways to handle it depending on what your business requirement is

```
try:
    # sql insert command here

except IntegrityError:
    # tell the user here.
```

The other option is to use the database to gracefully handle this using the [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause

> The optional ON CONFLICT clause specifies an alternative action to
>   raising a unique violation or exclusion constraint violation error.
>   For each individual row proposed for insertion, either the insertion
>   proceeds, or, if an arbiter constraint or index specified by
>   conflict_target is violated, the alternative conflict_action is taken.
>   ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING simply avoids inserting a row as its
>   alternative action. ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE updates the existing row
>   that conflicts with the row proposed for insertion as its alternative
>   action.

Comment: I've resolved with `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT fb_post_pkey DO NOTHING`